# Infinite loop with While is very processor-intensive

Tags: infinite-loop

This simple line of code:

```
While[True, Pause[1]]
```

uses 55% of one CPU core on my computer. Are there more efficient ways to construct simple infinite loops in Mathematica?

*Edit*

I'm on OS X 10.9.1 using Mathematica 10.0.

Further inspection:
`While[True,]` uses 100% CPU; `While[True, x]` also uses 100% CPU; `Pause[10]` uses 55% CPU for the time it is waiting, so 10 seconds in this case.

Comment: Strange, uses basically no resources on my machine...

Comment: Same here. No processor load at all. Could you please specify your exact operating system and you *Mathematica* version?

Comment: How about `Manipulate`? It runs a very efficient "infinite loop"

Comment: OS X 10.9, Mathematica 9.01, gives large CPU usage for the `While`.

Comment: @bills: is it the while? What happens if you just do a long `Pause` with no `While`? Curious...

Comment: Why the `Pause`? This works just fine... `While[True,]`

Comment: Interestingly, I get pretty high CPU usage with both `While[True, x]` and with `Pause[10]` though the latter only lasts for 10 seconds.

Comment: I get high CPU usage both with `While[True,]` but not with `While[True, Pause[1]]` in MMa 8.0.4 under Windows 7 x64.

Comment: @rm-rf I need pause because I've also put an `EmitSound` function in there and I need to wait for the duration of the sound so it does not overlap.

Comment: Are you really using version 10? Discussing it may be a violation of your NDA.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Unfortunately I can't find the Prerelease Agreement anywhere, but I don't think I'm discussing any new functionality. If I'm wrong I will delete this question as soon as possible.

Comment: I can reproduce it in v9.0.1 and 8.0.4 (*not* prerelease), OS X 10.9.1, precisely 55% CPU usage (so maybe we have similar computers)

Comment: My preferred infinite loop is sitting on beach staring at the waves... :)

Answer (score 6):

This problem seem to be specific for MacOSX and it has nothing to do with the while-loop. If I do a simple

```
Pause[100]
```

on my OSX, I have a CPU load of about 60% on one processor. A simple `While[True,]` uses 100% of one CPU core (as expected). My colleague tested it on Windows 8 where the pure while-loop uses one core too. The `Pause[100]` on the other hand doesn't use CPU power at all.

When you combine the two to `While[True,Pause[1]]` the CPU spends most of the time in pause and the loop-repetition speed is too slow to be noticeable. This is the reason why on OSX you have a CPU load and on Linux and Windows you haven't.

There is one funny thing though: I wanted to know whether or not this is *real* cpu load and therefore, I wrote a short test-func (which might need adaption to your computer speed). I have no idea what this computes, but it computes *something* in parallel, so my whole system is used:

```
cf = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Sum[i Sin[x] + x^2 - 1/(1 + x), {i, 100}], 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True];

data = RandomReal[1, {200, 200, 200}];
cf[data]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

This uses all possible threads for **13.103 seconds**

[image]

When I now open a second *Mathematica* and start a `Pause[100]` there and re-run the other calculation it takes only **13.042 seconds**. Please note the red dots below which come from the pause command

[image]

I don't know what to conclude from this but one explanation is, that CPU usage from `Pause` is no real usage and you can ignore it.

Comment: At least on Windows, parallelized compiled functions tend to lock up the system by stealing all resources. I suppose this is a problem of the thread scheduler. Anyway, I think your results might be different if you use a different CPU-intensive test case e.g. matrix-matrix `Dot` in a loop.

Comment: @OleksandrR. That might be possible. If you look on the image above, you see that the `Pause` is shown as red dots. Actually, I have seen this the first time. Usually, the CPU usage is always in green.